# How can I write a script to install BleachBit only if the version installed is not a certain version?

Tags: bash, scripts, versions

I want to write a bash script to download and install BleachBit from a .deb file only if the version already installed is not 1.0. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Bleachbit is only version 0.9 in the official repositories and I cannot find a PPA with version 1.0 for Ubuntu Precise. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler version of your script, (keeping the humor intact :) ):

```
#!/bin/bash

## The && means that the script will run the next command only if this one
## succeeds, in other words, only if the string `version 1.0` is found.
bleachbit --version | grep -q 'version 1.0' &&
 echo "$(tput setaf 2)The elves have verified the BleachBit version.$(tput sgr0)" &&
   exit 0
## This block will only be executed if the grep above failed
wget -P ~/Downloads http://katana.oooninja.com/bleachbit/sf/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204.deb &&
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204.deb &&
 echo "$(tput setaf 2)The elves have installed BleachBit 1.0.$(tput sgr0)"
```

Note that I added `&&` to the end of each command, that way, you will avoid errors if any of the commands fail since the script will exit on the first failed command.

A safer approach would be to change the first command to:

```
bleachbit --version | awk '/version/{if($NF>=1){exit 0}else{exit 1}}'
```

This has the advantage that it will work fine for future versions, when the version number will be greater than `1`. The `$NF` in `awk` means the last field and `/version/` means the script will run on lines matching `version`. So, since the first line is:

```
info: starting BleachBit version 1.0
```

`awk` will test whether the last field (`1.0`) here is greater than or equal to one and will exit with a `0` status (success), if it is which means that the next block (`&&`) will be executed, and your script will stop.

You could also condense the entire thing to:

```
bleachbit --version | head -n 1 | awk '{if($NF>=1){exit 1}else{exit 0}}' &&
wget -P ~/Downloads http://katana.oooninja.com/bleachbit/sf/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204.deb &&
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204
```

But that comes at the expense of the poor elves.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, terdon! One issue I see with the use of && is that I need this code to be part of a larger script so I need things to move along if BleachBit is installed or not. So, for my purposes, I won't use &&. I like your idea of using awk to account for future versions but I have had a hard time understanding how to use awk; I'm still a scripting newbie!

Comment: @HarlemSquirrel feel free to post a Q if you like, and I'd be happy to explain this particular one in more detail if needed. As for `&&` that can be used in a script, that's how I normally do it but yes, not for larger blocks. I would certainly not use `grep -c 1.0` though because that will also match `version 0.8.1.0` for example and it will match `1.0` irrespective of whether that is actually even part of the version string. For example `version 0.7 revision 1.0`.

Comment: Very good point about using 'version 1.0' instead of '1.0' so I am changing my code!

Answer (score 1):

I put this short script together that seems to work for me! This also include a bit of my own brand of elvish humor. I am using this code in a larger script so I can copy and paste this conditional anywhere I need it.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check BleachBit Version and install if necessary
if [ "$(bleachbit --version | grep -c 'version 1.0')" = "0" ];
    then 
        wget -P ~/Downloads http://katana.oooninja.com/bleachbit/sf/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204.deb
        sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/bleachbit_1.0_all_ubuntu1204.deb
        echo "$(tput setaf 2)The elves have installed BleachBit 1.0.$(tput sgr0)"
    else
        echo "$(tput setaf 2)The elves have verified the BleachBit version.$(tput sgr0)"
fi
```